# Disable special function keys on Apple Wireless Keyboard when connected to iPad

Tags: ipad, keyboard

I'm currently using an Apple Wireless Keyboard connected via Bluetooth to my iPad. However, I have the habit of accidentally placing the keyboard in my backpack, where the function keys get accidentally depressed. Sometimes, it hits the <kbd>▶ ||</kbd> key, which will cause my iPad to start playing music. Is there anyway to disable the function keys without turning off the entire keyboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to manage the function keys connected to an iPad. Your better options would be to shut off bluetooth when you stop using your iPad (which is better for battery life too!), or shut off the keyboard itself.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem. similar, but quicker and easier solution: going into system preferences to turn off (and later turn back on bluetooth) takes too long.

Simply hold the keyboard's power button long enough to actually turn the keyboard off (not just put it to sleep). This way the play button won't activate the iPad if it gets accidentally clicked. Later, you can just turn on the keyboard and you're ready to go (and type).